# PowerShell script throws error but still produces results

Tags: powershell, printing, remote-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a print server with about 50 printers installed with various drivers and not all configurations are set the same. I am moving printers around to new IP addresses based on a new IP schema, and I need to track each printer, its old IP, and the new IP. Then I need to capture the existing configurations for each one so I can add the printer and keep the settings the same as before.

So, here's the situation. I used the following:

```
PS C:\Users\a> Get-Printer | Where-Object -Property Name -match seattle | Get-PrintConfiguration
```

The output is:

```
Get-PrintConfiguration : An error occurred while performing the specified operation.  See the error details for more information.
At line:1 char:60
+ Get-Printer | Where-Object -Property Name -match seattle | Get-PrintConfiguratio ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_PrinterConfiguration:ROOT/StandardCi...erConfiguration) [Get-PrintConfiguration], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8000ffff,Get-PrintConfiguration

Get-PrintConfiguration : An error occurred while performing the specified operation.  See the error details for more information.
At line:1 char:60
+ Get-Printer | Where-Object -Property Name -match seattle | Get-PrintConfiguratio ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_PrinterConfiguration:ROOT/StandardCi...erConfiguration) [Get-PrintConfiguration], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8000ffff,Get-PrintConfiguration


PrinterName     ComputerName    Collate    Color      DuplexingMode       
-----------     ------------    -------    -----      -------------       
Seattle_Coun...                 False      True       OneSided            
SeattleWhsLaser                 True       True       OneSided            
Seattle Ware...                 False      False      OneSided            
Seattle_Seco...                 True       False      OneSided            
Seattle_Test...                 True       True       OneSided            
SeattleCoun                     True       True       OneSided            
Seattle - SH...                 True       True       OneSided
```

If I shorten that line to:

```
PS C:\Users\a> Get-Printer | Where-Object -Property Name -match $city
```

The output is all 9 printers as I expect:

```
Name                           ComputerName    Type         DriverName                PortName        Shared   Published 
----                           ------------    ----         ----------                --------        ------   --------- 
Seattle_Test_Printer-Seattl...                 Local        HP Universal Printing PS  192.168.100.25  True     True      
Seattle_Second_Floor                           Local        HP Universal Printing ... IP_192.168.1... True     True      
Seattle_Counter_Laser                          Local        HP Universal Printing ... IP_192.168.1... True     False     
SeattleWhsLaser                                Local        HP Universal Printing ... 192.168.100.82  True     True      
SeattleCoun                                    Local        HP Universal Printing ... IP_192.168.1... True     True      
Seattle Warehouse ZDesigner...                 Local        ZDesigner 110XiIII Plu... 192.168.100.... True     True      
Seattle Upstairs OKI PCL6 C...                 Local        OKI PCL6 Class Driver     192.168.100.14  True     True      
Seattle - SHARP MX-5141N PCL6                  Local        SHARP MX-5141N PCL6       192.168.100.30  True     False     
Seattle (new) HP LaserJet P...                 Local        HP LaserJet P3011/P301... 192.168.100.25  True     True
```

I should get a total of 9 printers, but I cannot understand why I get the error for 2 printers and get good results for the rest? The ultimate goal is to make this automated and log all the changes.

Comment: Are you able to get the configuration settings when you run it against one of those two manually? Something like `Get-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName 'Seattle (new) HP LaserJet Printer'` (you may need to fix the name, it's truncated in your question so I just guessed)

Comment: Actually no, but that did lead me to the discovery I have a total of 12 printers, but 9 are showing up in PS. Of the 9 that are showing up, the 2 that are missing appear to missing their drivers, so that clears that up. You've led me to a couple of discoveries (1) I have at least 2 printers without full drivers installed (but people can still print to them) (2) I see 12 printers for this branch in print mgr (3) the missing 3 printers are up and live. Now I'm really confused. @TheMadTechnician

Comment: You could try invoking the CIM method that pulls the config directly such as `Get-CimInstance -ClassName MSFT_Printer -Namespace 'ROOT/StandardCimv2'|%{Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName MSFT_PrinterConfiguration -Namespace 'ROOT/StandardCimv2' -MethodName GetByPrinterName -Arguments @{'PrinterName'=$_.Name} |% cmdletOutput}` and see if that nets you more results.

Comment: Are you running your Powershell session elevated (assuming you are running this directly on the printserver) and does the account running this script actually has permissions to read the properties? The error code is similair to errors you get when mapping a printer manually while lacking permissions.

Comment: I asked some others to see if they had the same issue, and it is a permissions issue, even with PS as Admin. Thanks for the help. @bluuf

Comment: That definitely gets me more, but it gets all branches. I tried to add a where condition, but I must've been putting it in the wrong place. How would I limit the result to 1 branch at a time? This is my current statement that gets me all the printers I can access by branch `where {($_.location -split '\.')[2] -eq $locationNumber 
            -or ($_.sharename -match $city) 
            -or ($_.name -match $city) 
            -or ($_.location -match $city)}` @TheMadTechnician

Comment: Add that `Where` statement after the first command, and before the first `ForEach` loop (I use the alias `%` in my comment above). So `Get-CimInstance -ClassName MSFT_Printer -Namespace 'ROOT/StandardCimv2'| **<YOUR WHERE STATEMENT HERE>** |%{`

Comment: That worked awesome! One more question for you. If I wanted to hash each printer driver with the printer's IP before I move them, how would I do that? I think it would be a `.getrelated('win32_printer') and add it to an empty hash table, that should work, right? @TheMadTechnician

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Printer` and `Get-PrintConfiguration` are really just wrappers for `Get-CimInstance` calls to make things easier on us. We can use the CIM object to do all of this, and sometimes it works better that way. To get your printers, use this:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName MSFT_Printer -Namespace 'ROOT/StandardCimv2'
```

Then you can pipe that into a `Where` statement (as provided by you) to refine the results to just the ones you want:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName MSFT_Printer -Namespace 'ROOT/StandardCimv2' | where {($_.location -split '\.')[2] -eq $locationNumber -or ($_.sharename -match $city) -or ($_.name -match $city) -or ($_.location -match $city)}
```

After that you can invoke the `GetByPrinterName` method of the MSFT_PrinterConfiguration class to get the configuration for each printer (in a `ForEach` loop) like this:

```
|%{Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName MSFT_PrinterConfiguration -Namespace 'ROOT/StandardCimv2' -MethodName GetByPrinterName -Arguments @{'PrinterName'=$_.Name} |% cmdletOutput}
```

So, if it were me I'd do something like this:

```
$Printers = Get-CimInstance -ClassName MSFT_Printer -Namespace 'ROOT/StandardCimv2' | where {($_.location -split '\.')[2] -eq $locationNumber -or ($_.sharename -match $city) -or ($_.name -match $city) -or ($_.location -match $city)}
$Output = @{}
ForEach($Printer in $Printers){
    $Config = Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName MSFT_PrinterConfiguration -Namespace 'ROOT/StandardCimv2' -MethodName GetByPrinterName -Arguments @{'PrinterName'=$Printer.Name} |% cmdletOutput
    $Printer | Add-Member 'ConfigInfo' $Config
    $Output.add($Printer.Name,$Printer)
}
```

So what that does is gets all the printers, and filters for just the branch you specify. Then it makes an empty hashtable. Then it loops through the printers, and for each one it recovers the config info for that printer. Then it adds that to the printer object as the 'ConfigInfo' property. Lastly it adds a record to the hashtable for that printer's name, with the modified printer object as the value. So in the end you could do:

```
$Output['Seattle_Counter_Laser']
```

And that would show you the printer's info like what driver its running, and what the IP address is listed on the Port.

Or if you want to look it up by the IP in the PortName property you could do something like:

```
$Output.values|Where{$_.PortName -match '192.168.100.82'}
```

Then to get the configuration info you can do:

```
$Output['Seattle_Counter_Laser'].ConfigInfo
```

I would export that whole hashtable using `Export-CliXml` and keep it someplace safe, because if things go sideways and the printers all stop working you have everything you need in that file to restore them back to how they are right now.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to share that script and **how** it all works. I'll try that and let you know I've succeeded! @TheMadTechnician

Comment: Is it possible in PS v4 the MSFT_PrinterConfiguration was renamed or iss accessed another way? I get an error and I found `-ClassName MSFT_PrinterConfiguration` is not a listed option.

Comment: It might be different depending on OS. The above was done on my Win10 machine. To find out, run `Get-PrintConfiguration` against a printer that works and pipe that to `Get-Member` and look at the top for the TypeName. For instance, mine shows `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_PrinterConfiguration`. You need everything past the # character. The very end is the class, and the things before it are the namespace. So for me the NameSpace is `ROOT/StandardCimv2` and the class is `MSFT_PrinterConfiguration`. You may need to adjust those for your computer.

Comment: I feel like I'm hounding you, very sorry. It just seems tougher than it should be. I now get the error "Add" with "2" arguments: "Key cannot be null. Parm name: key". I changed 2nd param to be `$Output.add($Printer.Name,$Printer.ConfigInfo)` and it's still complaining. I also tried other properties and no difference. Again, I _really_ appreciate you taking so much time to hel. @TheMadTechnician

Comment: That tells me that `$Printer.Name` is blank. Make sure that all of the printer objects in `$Printers` have something in the Name property.

Comment: Now I get this weird error that says "Invoke-CimMethod : One or more parameter values passed to the method were invalid." This just started out of the blue. I have closed the PS session and started it again to make sure it wasn't something weird with the session. I would guess this has something to do with the null values before? @TheMadTechnician

Comment: I pulled a `GoodPrinter | gm` and my only options are Clone, Dispose, Equals, GetCimSessionCompName and InstanceID, GetHash, GetObjectData, GetType and ToString as available methods. PrinterName does show as a property, but obviously I cannot call it by `-MethodName`. If I call it as a property I should still be able to put into the hash table, right? But it'll still require a methodname. @TheMadTechnician

Comment: You're sure it says `PrinterName` and not just `Name` for the property? According to the [class details](http://wutils.com/wmi/root/standardcimv2/msft_printer/) it should just be `Name`. You are trying to call the `Name` property in the hashtable `@{'PrinterName'=$Printer.Name}`

Comment: I did `Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName MSFT_PrinterConfiguration`.`Invoke-CimMethod : Invalid class 
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName MSFT_PrinterConfiguration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (root\cimv2:MSFT_PrinterConfiguration: 
   String) [Invoke-CimMethod], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure. CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand` but GM = `TypeName: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_PrinterConfiguration`

Comment: This is what it shows `PrinterName               Property       string PrinterName {get;}`. I've also tried changing it from `@{'PrinterName'=$Printer.Name}` to `@{'PrinterName'=$Printer.PrinterName}`.

Comment: Looks like you left the `-NameSpace` off your `Invoke-CimMethod` command.

Comment: It's still the same error `Invoke-CimMethod : One or more parameter values passed to the method were invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace 'ROOT/StandardCimv2' -ClassName msft_printerconfigur 
...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (ROOT/StandardCi...erconfiguration:S 
   tring) [Invoke-CimMethod], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 4,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCm 
   dlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand`

Comment: No, that's a different error. The previous one was invalid class. This one is invalid parameter value. Try this: `$Printers | FT Name,PortName,DriverName` and make sure all printers have a name. Maybe do a `$Printers.Count` and make sure that it is the right number compared to what the first command displays.

Comment: They all come back blank. I have gone into the Print Manager and verified all printers have names. I don't know if this add to the problem, but there are 2 printers I cannot access for one reason or other, but they are not included in the `$Printers.Count` result.

Comment: Ok, try `$Printers[0]|GM` and tell me what the `TypeName` is.

Comment: Perhaps we should move this to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143217/powershell-script-throws-error-but-still-produces-results). Comments are not intended to have a conversation.

Comment: TypeName: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT
_PrinterConfiguration. I don't have enough reputation to move it or chat.

Comment: Please click **[this link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143217/powershell-script-throws-error-but-still-produces-results)** to join the chat room.

Comment: I can't reply in there, but we are in the same area; practically neighbors. Is there a way you can securely share a skype or hangouts ID?